# input range materialize no me toma el valor de una variable php

Tags: php, materialize

```
<?php 

$estatus = $resultado['status'];

 echo '<p class="range-field">


     <input type="range"   value= "$estatus" disabled>

    </p>';
echo $estatus;

    ?>
```

uso la siguientes lineas para mostrar una barra que me indicara el estado de una solicitud usando materialize.

estoy mostrando mediante echo el valor del $estatus pero no me lo esta tomando en el medidor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que no entiendo es por que el valor impreso no lo toma el medidor.

luego de indicarle un minimo y un maximo tampoco funciona se coloca en el 6

```
<input type="range"   value="$estatus" min="1" max="10" >
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo creo que lo está tomando, pero no se nota porque no tiene un mínimo y un máximo, prueba con esto: <input type="range" value="$estatus" min="1" max="10" />.

Comment: eso lo intente pero se mueve un poco despues de la mitad, se coloca en el 6...

Comment: ¿Entonces no tendrás algún estilo que esté alterando el diseño del range?

Comment: no, de hecho estoy probando a colocarle el 1,2,3 y si los toma...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas asignando a value "$estatus" como un string. No estas asignando el valor de la variable.

Prueba hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php 

$estatus = $resultado['status'];

 echo '<p class="range-field">
            <input type="range"   value= "'.$estatus.'" disabled>
      </p>';
echo $estatus;

  ?>
```

De este modo estamos concatenando el valor de la variable. Con eso se debería solucionar. Saludos!

Comment: gracias, olvide que en php la cosa cambia (y) esta es la respuesta correcta.